# Angular app not working within mobile browser

Tags: angularjs, node.js, google-maps

I have an Angular app hosted with AWS that works perfectly on desktop, however with mobile the app is broken. In Firefox and Chrome emulators, the app works fine. Any ideas as to why this is happening? The app uses the Google Maps API.

Comment: Could be any number of things. Whats the URL..?

Comment: http://fairwayfinder.net/js/angular-google-maps-street-view_dev_mapped.min.js.map Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ui.bootstrap due to:
[$injector:nomod] Module 'ui.bootstrap' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: courseController.js:85 SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'location' All from iPhone safari debugger

Comment: ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js:10 SyntaxError: Unexpected EOF

Comment: Thanks @JustinHerter , I was planning on looking into the Remote Debugger for android and iOS console for iPhone

Comment: It seems to be working fine on Android devices, and breaking on iOS devices.

Comment: The issue was the ui-bootstarp-tpls injection. Took that out, works across all devices